# db2 query to select the first row fetched

Tags: select, db2

I have a query like

```
UPDATE PRD_PRODUCT_L10N ppl
 SET ( CATCHING_PHRASE
    , GENERIC_NAME
    , INGREDIENTS
    , QUANTITY
    , DOSE
    , NUTRITION_FACTS
    , PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
    , PROMOTION_MESSAGE
    , MESSAGE
   ) = (
   SELECT distinct CATCHING_PHRASE
        , GENERIC_NAME
        , INGREDIENTS
        , QUANTITY
        , DOSE
        , NUTRITION_FACTS
        , PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
        , PROMOTION_MESSAGE
        , MESSAGE
    FROM  TEMP_UPLOAD_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES tupa
    INNER JOIN
          PRD_PRODUCT                    pp
      ON  pp .EISIDENTIFIER = tupa.EISIDENTIFIER
    WHERE ppl.PRODUCTGUID   = pp.GUID
      AND ppl.LOCALEGUID     = tupa.LOCALEGUID
   )
 WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 0
    FROM  TEMP_UPLOAD_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES tupa
    INNER JOIN
          PRD_PRODUCT                    pp
      ON  pp .EISIDENTIFIER = tupa.EISIDENTIFIER
    WHERE ppl.PRODUCTGUID   = pp  .GUID
      AND ppl.LOCALEGUID     = tupa.LOCALEGUID
   )
```

the subquery returns more than 1 row and I would like to insert the first selected. How do I do that in DB2 database?

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Depending on your DB2 version (i think 8 upwards) you can use fetch at your subquery

(select * from table fetch first 1 rows only)

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.admin%2Ffrstnrw.htm

Answer (score 5):

Add [`FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000875.html) to your subquery.  Search for `fetch-first-clause` on the page linked for more info.  This is for DB2 on Linux/Unix/Windows.

If you're on the Mainframe (v9), then you want [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_fetchfirstclause.htm) for more info (or [version 10](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_fetchfirstclause.htm)).